# "indexOf()" não encontra elemento em um array

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo-de-busca

O `indexOf()` esta me retornando -1 mesmo eu tendo esse elemento, estou fazendo assim:

```
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})

console.log(pessoas)

function encontrar() {

if(pessoas.indexOf('Pedro') < 0) {
    console.log('Não existe');
  }else {
  console.log('Já existe');
  }

}

encontrar()
```

> eu tentei do seguinte jeito e dá erro:

```
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})

console.log(pessoas)

function encontrar() {

if(pessoas.nome.indexOf('Pedro') < 0) {
    console.log('Não existe');
  }else {
  console.log('Já existe');
  }

}

encontrar()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para encontrar objetos dentro de um array, utilize o `findIndex`, assim:

```js
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})

console.log(pessoas)

function encontrar() {

if(pessoas.findIndex(x => x.nome === 'Pedro') < 0) {
    console.log('Não existe');
  }else {
    console.log('Já existe');
  }

}

encontrar()
```

Por que não funciona com objetos?

Inicialmente, você fez a comparação de forma errada. Se fosse comparar, teria que comparar com o objeto dentro do indice, no caso, `pessoas.indexOf({nome: "Pedro"});` entretanto, isto também não irá funcionar.
Isso por que, para o javascript, cada objeto é único, mesmo que seu valor seja idêntico. Uma prova? Veja:

```js
var a = {} // objeto vazio
var b = {} // outro objeto vazio

console.log(a === b); // false
```

Então quando você coloca outro objeto dentro, ele tenta comparar o objeto que está dentro do `indexOf` com o que está dentro do array. Vai sempre retornar falso.

Por isso não é possível fazer com o indexOf, e então teria que procurar outras formas de fazer.

Comment: então pelo que entendi, o indexOf só encontra elementos da qual não possuem objetos dentro, é isso?

Comment: Vou editar com a explicação do porque não funciona com objetos.

Answer (score 7):

Vamos imprimir o que está mandando pesquisar:

```js
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})
for (let pessoa of pessoas) console.log(pessoa);
```

Note que ele tem objetos, ele não tem textos. No primeiro exemplo está comparando com um texto, não vai funcionar mesmo, um objeto nunca é igual a um texto simples, eles já são de tipos diferentes, não tem como ser igual.

No segundo está usando um membro de um objeto para comparar com um texto, acontece que `pessoas` não é um `object` é um *array* com objetos dentro dele, cada ele mento é um objeto, mas não ele como um todo, então também não faz sentido.

Se puder mudar `pessoas` dependendo de como mude é possível fazer o primeiro ou o segundo funcionar, mas seria algo bem diferente. Se mudar a estrutura de `pessoas` uma das formas é procurar na mão (eu a prefiro porque é sempre a mais rápida de todas as opções, pode testar cada uma delas). Algo assim:

```js
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})

function encontrar() {
    for (let pessoa of pessoas) {
        if (pessoa.nome === 'Pedro') {
            console.log('Já existe');
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log('Não existe');
}
encontrar()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Find.js).

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o **map** pra retornar:

```
var pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})

function encontrar() {

var retornoIndex = pessoas.map(function(e) { return e.nome; }).indexOf('Pedro');

if(retornoIndex < 0) {
    console.log('Não existe');
  }else {
  console.log('Já existe');
  }

}

encontrar();
```

Comment: Com indexOf não é possível?

Comment: @PedroSilva no seu caso você tem um array que nao contem tipos primitivos. Há algumas formas de encontrar o item na lista, esta é uma opção

Answer (score 4):

Usar `indexOf` seria viável se seu array contivesse apenas tipos primitivos nesse caso use `Array.prototype.findIndex()`

> Nota: O método findIndex() retorna o índice do primeiro elemento na
>   matriz que satisfaz a função de teste fornecida . Caso contrário,
>   retorna -1, indicando que nenhum elemento passou no teste.
>   Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```js
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push({"nome": "Pedro"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "João"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "Maria"})
pessoas.push({"nome": "José"})

function encontrar() {

if(pessoas.findIndex(i => i.nome === "Pedro") < 0) {
    console.log('Não existe');
  }else {
  console.log('Já existe');
  }

}

encontrar()
```

Answer (score 3):

Você está procurando index onde não existe. Por isso não encontra. O correto desse código seria esse:

```
pessoas = [];
pessoas.push("Pedro")
pessoas.push("João")
pessoas.push("Maria")
pessoas.push("José")

console.log(pessoas)

function encontrar() {

if(pessoas.indexOf('Pedro') < 0) {
    console.log('Não existe');
  }else {
  console.log('Já existe');
  }

}

encontrar()
```

O indexOf ta procurando o "Pedro" só que dentro do array ele está achando só um objeto com outros valores. Para encontra valores no objeto pode utilizar o filter().